# Using free on structure which contains unintialized pointer

Tags: c, struct, free

I have structure with an integer and character pointer. I am just allocation memory for the structure. Now if try to free the same structure, pointer will also be freed?

```
struct a
{
int b;
char *c
};
main()
{
struct *d = malloc(sizeof(a));
free(d);
}
```

There is no memory leak in above programm?

Answer (score 0):

In order for there to be a memory leak, there has to be something that was allocated that can no longer be referenced.  Since the only thing allocated here is what was explicitly freed, there was no leak.

The fact that you have a pointer in the structure is irrelevant, since you never allocated anything for it to point to.